# No me imprime el error o el informe en codigo de inventario java

Tags: java, condiciones

hice este código y me imprime unos valores bien en mi caso de prueba, se supone que si el producto existe dependiendo si es: ACTUALIZAR,BORRAR,AGREGAR, debe realizar la acción y adicional imprimir un informe, con el primer caso de prueba no hace nada pero con el segundo si da, no se que pueda ser

Los datos de ingreso son dos líneas la primera es la acción y la segunda es el producto con sus características

La salida estará representada por una única línea formada por un único valor:

Valor del inventario
Este valor debe imprimirse después de realizar las operaciones solicitadas en la entrada de datos.
El valor del inventario debe imprimirse con un número decimal
En caso de solicitar ACTUALIZAR o BORRAR un producto que no existe (es decir, que el código del producto no se encuentra en la base de datos), se debe imprimir 'ERROR'
En caso de solicitar AGREGAR un producto cuyo código ya existe en la base de datos se debe imprimir 'ERROR'

Caso de prueba:

*BORRAR

10 Jamon 15000 10*

*AGREGAR

11 Melon 70 13*

```
public class Reto2 {
   private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   
   public String read(){
   return this.scanner.nextLine();
          
   }
       
   public void run() {
               
       String entradaAccion= read ();
       String entradaCadena= read();
       String[] Lista = entradaCadena.split(" ");
       
       int codigo= Integer.parseInt(Lista[0]);
       String nombre= Lista[1];  
       double precio=Double.parseDouble(Lista[2]);
       int inventario=Integer.parseInt(Lista[3]);
       
       Producto producto  = new Producto(codigo, nombre, precio, inventario);
       BaseDatosProducto bdpProductos= new BaseDatosProducto();
                                   
       if (!bdpProductos.ValidarExistencia(producto)){
           if(entradaAccion.equals("AGREGAR")) {
               bdpProductos.AGREGAR(producto);
               bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
               }
               else {
                   System.out.println("ERROR");
               } 
               
       }else if (bdpProductos.ValidarExistencia(producto)) {
           if(entradaAccion.equals("ACTUALIZAR")) {
               bdpProductos.ACTUALIZAR(producto);
               bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
               }
           }else if (entradaAccion.equals("BORRAR")){
               bdpProductos.BORRAR(producto);
               bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
               } 
           else {
                   System.out.println("ERROR");}
   }
   
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Reto2 programa = new Reto2();
       programa.run();
           
   }
       

}
class Producto {
   private int codigo;
   private String nombre;  
   private double precio;
   private int inventario;         
   
   public Producto(int codigo, String nombre, double precio, int inventario) {
       this.codigo= codigo;
       this.nombre=nombre;
       this.precio=precio;
       this.inventario=inventario;
       
   }

   public Producto() {
       
   }

   public int getCodigo() {
       return codigo;
   }

   public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
       this.codigo = codigo;
   }

   public String getNombre() {
       return nombre;
   }

   public void setNombre(String nombre) {
       this.nombre = nombre;
   }
   public double getPrecio() {
       return precio;
   }

   public void setPrecio(double precio) {
       this.precio = precio;
   }

   public int getInventario() {
       return inventario;
   }

   public void setInventario(int inventario) {
       this.inventario = inventario;
   }
   
}
import java.util.HashMap;

class BaseDatosProducto  {
    
   
   private HashMap <Integer,Producto> listaProductos = new HashMap<>();
   
   public BaseDatosProducto() {    
       listaProductos.put(1, new Producto(1, "Manzanas", 5000.0, 25));
       listaProductos.put(2, new Producto(2,"Limones",2300.0,15));
       listaProductos.put(3, new Producto(3,"Peras",2700.0,33));
       listaProductos.put(4, new Producto(4,"Arandanos",9300.0,5));
       listaProductos.put(5, new Producto(5,"Tomates",2100.0,42));
       listaProductos.put(6, new Producto(6,"Fresas",4100.0,3));
       listaProductos.put(7, new Producto(7,"Helado",4500.0,41));
       listaProductos.put(8, new Producto(8,"Galletas",500.0,8));
       listaProductos.put(9, new Producto(9,"Chocolates",3500.0,80));
       listaProductos.put(10, new Producto(10,"Jamon",15000.0,10));
       }
   
   public boolean ValidarExistencia(Producto producto) {
       return this.listaProductos.containsKey(producto.getCodigo());
       
       
   }
       
   public void AGREGAR(Producto p) {
       this.listaProductos.put(p.getCodigo(),p);
   }
   public void BORRAR(Producto p) {    
       this.listaProductos.remove(p.getCodigo(),p);
   }
   public void ACTUALIZAR(Producto p) {
       this.listaProductos.replace(p.getCodigo(), p);
   }
   public void GenerarInforme() {
       
       Double Total= Total();
       System.out.println(Total);
   }
       private Double  Total() {
       
       double ValrTotal = 0;
       double Resultado =0;
       
       
       for(Producto p: listaProductos.values()) {
           ValrTotal=(p.getPrecio()* p.getInventario());
            Resultado += ValrTotal;
       
       }
       return  (double) (Math.round(Resultado* 10) / 10.0f) ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira este código:

```
if( !bdpProductos.ValidarExistencia( producto ) ) {
   System.out.println( entradaAccion );
   if( entradaAccion.equals( "AGREGAR" ) ) {
      System.out.println( "popo" );
      bdpProductos.AGREGAR( producto );
      bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
   }
   else {
      System.out.println( "ERROR" );
   }
}
else if( bdpProductos.ValidarExistencia( producto ) ) {
   System.out.println( "pipi" );
   if( entradaAccion.equals( "ACTUALIZAR" ) ) {
      bdpProductos.ACTUALIZAR( producto );
      bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
   }
}
else if( entradaAccion.equals( "BORRAR" ) ) {
   bdpProductos.BORRAR( producto );
   bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
}
else {
   System.out.println( "ERROR" );
}
```

Si el producto no está en la base, entra en el primer **if**, si está en la base, entra en el segundo... como no existe otro posibilidad (o está o no está) jamás va a entrar en el tercero o cuarto.
Posible solución:

```
if( bdpProductos.ValidarExistencia( producto ) ) {
       // si quieres agregar un producto que ya está... 
    if( entradaAccion.equals( "AGREGAR" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "ERROR" ); 
    }
    else if( entradaAccion.equals( "ACTUALIZAR" ) ) {
       bdpProductos.ACTUALIZAR( producto );
       bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
    }
    else if( entradaAccion.equals( "BORRAR" ) ) {
       bdpProductos.BORRAR( producto );
       bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
    }
}
else {
    if( entradaAccion.equals( "AGREGAR" ) ) {
       bdpProductos.AGREGAR( producto );
       bdpProductos.GenerarInforme();
    }

       // si quieres borrar o actualizar un producto que no está... 
    else if( entradaAccion.equals( "ACTUALIZAR" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "ERROR" );;
    }
    else if( entradaAccion.equals( "BORRAR" ) ) {
       System.out.println( "ERROR" );
    }

}
```